# Optimizing Bash script, subshell removal

Tags: linux, bash, optimization

I have a bash script that lists the amount of ip addresses connected on a port. My issue is, is that with large amounts of connections it is slow as poo. I think it is because of the subshells in use, but I am having trouble removing them without borking the rest of the script. Here is the script in its entirety as it is fairly short:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    portnumber=80
    reversedns_enabled=0

    [ ! -z "${1}" ] && portnumber=${1}
    [ ! -z "${2}" ] && reversedns_enabled=${2}

    #this will hold all of our ip addresses extracted from netstat
    ipaddresses=""

    #get all of our connected ip addresses
    while read line; do
            ipaddress=$( echo ${line} | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed s/:[^:]*$// )
            ipaddresses="${ipaddresses}${ipaddress}\n"
    done < <( netstat -ano | grep -v unix | grep ESTABLISHED | grep \:${portnumber} )

    #remove trailing newline
    ipaddresses=${ipaddresses%%??}

    #output of program
    finaloutput=""

    #get our ip addresses sorted, uniq counted, and reverse sorted based on amount of uniq
    while read line; do
            if [[ ${reversedns_enabled} -eq 1 ]]; then
                    reversednsname=""       

                    #we use justipaddress to do our nslookup(remove the count of uniq)
                    justipaddress=$( echo ${line} | cut -d' ' -f2 )
                    reversednsstring=$( host ${justipaddress} )
                    if echo "${reversednsstring}" | grep -q "domain name pointer"; then
                            reversednsname=$( echo ${reversednsstring} | grep -o "pointer .*" | cut -d' ' -f2 )
                    else
                            reversednsname="reverse-dns-not-found"
                    fi

                    finaloutput="${finaloutput}${line} ${reversednsname}\n"
            else
                    finaloutput="${finaloutput}${line}\n"
            fi
    done < <( echo -e ${ipaddresses} | uniq -c | sort -r )

    #tabulate that sheet son
    echo -e ${finaloutput} | column -t
```

The majority of the time spent is doing this operation: `echo ${line} | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed s/:[^:]*$//` what is the best way to inline this to produce a faster script. It takes well over a second with 1000 concurrent users (which is my base target, although should be able to process more without using up all of my cpu).

Comment: This is not an unreasonable script. Try running it from the command line using the `-v` option to `bash` -- e.g. `bash -v script-name`. That option will print each line as it is read. See if any noticeable delay occurs just after a line is printed to the screen. That would be the place to start looking for performance issues in your script.

Comment: Aha, thank you for that, I did not know of the -v switch. So, the issue is with the subshells I believe- this line in particular: echo ${line} | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed s/:[^:]*$//

Comment: I appreciate that @ElliottFrisch, you are correct.

Comment: Add the `-t` option to `netstat` to restrict the output to just TCP sockets (So you don't need to filter out UNIX sockets), and remove the `-o` option since you don't seem to be doing anything with the extra timing output. Also, all that buffering in to variables is unnecessary if you embrace pipelines; for example, here's a single pipeline that I believe accomplishes what the non-reverse-DNS branch of your code above does: `netstat -nta | awk 'match($4,/:80$/) && $6=="ESTABLISHED" {sub(/:[0-9]+/,"",$5); print $5}' | uniq -c | column -t | sort -nr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce that with `cut -d' ' <<< "$line" | sed ...`.  You could write a more complex `sed` script and avoid the use of `cut`.

But the real benefit would be in avoiding the loop so there's only one `sed` (or `awk` or `perl` or …) script involved.  I'd probably look to reduce it to `ipaddresses=$(netstat -ano | awk '...')` so that instead of 3 `grep` processes, plus one `cut` and `sed` per line, there was just a single `awk` process.

```
ipaddresses=$(netstat -ano |
              awk " /unix/           { next }  # grep -v unix
                   !/ESTABLISHED/    { next }  # grep ESTABLISHED
                   !/:${portnumber}/ { next }  # grep :${portnum}  "'
                                     { sub(/:[^:]*$/, "", $5); print $5; }'
             )
```

That's probably rather clumsy, but it is a fairly direct transliteration of the existing code.  Watch for the quotes to get `${portnumber}` into the regex.

Since you feed the list of IP addresses into `uniq -c` and `sort -r`. You probably should use `sort -rn`, and you could use `awk` to do the `uniq -c`, too.

The only bit that you can't readily improve is `host`; that seems to only take one host or IP address argument at a time, so you have to run it for each name or address.

Comment: Yes, `awk` would be a very good choice to replace everything in the first loop that is applied to the output of `netstat`. That includes the three invocations of `grep`...

Comment: Very interesting, extremely fast as compared to before as well. Time to learn some awk!

Comment: Replacing a process — or three processes — per line with a single process for all lines is almost invariably a huge performance win.  I can't think of many situations in which it would not be a big win.

Comment: For examples of `awk`, see [Programming Pearls](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/). Almost all of the articles were originally printed in the [Communications of the ACM](http://cacm.acm.org/) to present small programming problems and solutions. `Awk` was used for the code samples even though the articles were not about `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a stab at a couple of issues:

The following line from the script which performs incremental string concatenation will not be be efficient without the means to allocate a reasonable buffer:

```
ipaddresses="${ipaddresses}${ipaddress}\n"
```

For another, using a `while` loop with `read line` when a pipeline will do is significantly worse than the pipeline. Try something like this instead of the first loop:

```
netstat -ano |
grep -v 'unix' |
grep 'ESTABLISHED' |
grep "\:${portnumber}" |
cut -d' ' -f5 |
sed 's/:[^:]*$//' |
while read line; do ...
```

Also, try combining at least two of the three sequential `grep` commands into one invocation of `grep`.

If nothing else, this will mean you are no longer spawning a pipeline which creates new `cut` and `sed` processes for each line of input processed in the first loop.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you here, but as far as I can tell the pipeline into while method will not actually work? Is it just an toward refactoring or should it actually be working as is?

Comment: @jett Whether you redirect into a Unix shell `while` loop using a pipe -- i.e. `|` -- or another stream redirection like `<` makes no difference. That is a feature of Unix shells, pipe, and standard input, output, and error.

Comment: @jett As far as any performance with "subshells" in your script, the single best thing you can do is to use pipes and not spawn new Unix processes for each line of input. Either the body of a `while` loop should use only Bash built-in commands, or the work per line performed in the body of the loop should be significant enough per line of input to justify the resources used. But again, if a pipeline can be used instead of a `while` loop use it. Use it even if you need to use temporary files as buffers because of the requirements of conditional logic.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a whole script optimized & refactored:

```
#!/bin/bash

portnumber=80
reversedns_enabled=0

[[ $1 ]] && portnumber=$1
[[ $2 ]] && reversedns_enabled=$2

#this will hold all of our ip addresses extracted from netstat
ipaddresses=''

#get all of our connected ip addresses
while IFS=' :' read -r type _ _ _ _ ipaddress port state _; do
    if [[ $type != 'unix' && $port == "$portnumber" && $state == 'ESTABLISHED' ]]; then
        ipaddresses+="$ipaddress\n"
    fi
done < <(netstat -ano)

#remove trailing newline
ipaddresses=${ipaddresses%%??}

#output of program
finalOutput=""

#get our ip addresses sorted, uniq counted, and reverse sorted based on amount of uniq
while read -r line; do
    if (( reversedns_enabled == 1 )); then
        reverseDnsName=""

        #we use justipaddress to do our nslookup(remove the count of uniq)
        read -r _ justipaddress _ <<< "$line"
        reverseDnsString=$(host "$justipaddress")
        if [[ $reverseDnsString == *'domain name pointer'* ]]; then
            reverseDnsName=${reverseDnsName##*domain name pointer }
        else
            reverseDnsName="reverse-dns-not-found"
        fi

        finalOutput+="$line $reverseDnsName\n"
    else
        finalOutput+="$line\n"
    fi
done < <(echo -e "$ipaddresses" | sort -ur)

#tabulate that sheet son
echo -e "$finalOutput" | column -t
```

As you can see, there are almost no external tools used (no sed, awk or grep). Awesome!